# MVC3 client validation: how to prevent page reloading?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, client-side-validation

I have page with form:

```
    @using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "Theme", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "frm_post", enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
    {    
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Name)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Name)
        <input type="image" src="img.png"
 onclick="javascript:if(func()){document.getElementById('frm_post').submit();}else{return false;}"/>
    }
```

I included scripts to page:

```
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.5.2.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

I have such strings in web.config:

```
<appSettings>
    <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true"/> 
    <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true"/> 
</appSettings>
```

I have [Required] for Name in Model.

But when I left textbox Name empty and submit form, error message is shown for some seconds and then page reload. How can I stop reloading of page?

Comment: Why do you need this onclick event on the submit button in which you are manually forcing a submit on the form? Makes no sense to me. That's exactly what the unobtrusive validation already does for you.

Comment: Yeah... It was mistake. I just should remove form.submit() from onclick event of my button. So, if I use
`<input type="image" src="img.png"
 onclick="javascript:if(!func()){return false;}"/>`,
it works fine.

Comment: what's the point of this onclick handler? Why do you need it?

Comment: I use onclick to check some additional conditions (inside function func). But now it works fine. The clue is concluded.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O-o-ops... I just should remove form.submit() from onclick event of my button.
So, if I use

```
<input type="image" src="img.png"
 onclick="javascript:if(!func()){return false;}"/>
```

it works fine.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you might want to remove that inline onclick handler and consider writing instead a custom validator.  This http://blogs.msdn.com/b/stuartleeks/archive/2011/01/25/asp-net-mvc-3-integrating-with-the-jquery-ui-date-picker-and-adding-a-jquery-validate-date-range-validator.aspx is a good example of how to write one in MVC3 using unobtrusive validation.  It's for a custom datepicker but the same principle can be applied for your custom validation.